# Can't tell the difference between permutation and combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In an exam, a student has to answer 6 out of 8 questions. How many ways can she answer the 6 questions if

a) there are no restrictions?
b) The first 3 questions are compulsory?
c) she must answer at least 3 of the first  4 questions?

I am confused. Why is this question combination? I thought it is supposed to be a permutation. The 6 questions that the student is supposed to answer are specific. For example, each question is unique on its own. That is my understanding, but its wrong ._. Can anyone correct my logic?

Comment: a **permutation** is a bijective application whereas a **combinaison** is a "number of possibilities"

Comment: @Surb Is combinations the number of permutations?

Comment: @M.Winter : The question of the OP the very ambiguous at this point, but there is a priori no link between those two concepts.

Comment: Don't bother about names. The essential point is that you recognize a combinatorial situation and act accordingly.

Comment: A permutation can be viewed as a linear arrangement. A permutation has an "ordering" to it. Combinations neglect such an order. For instance, consider the set $\{1,2,3\}$. There are six permutations of all three elements:

1,2,3;
1,3,2;
2,1,3;
2,3,1;
3,2,1; and
3,1,2. However there is only one combination of all three elements since these are just the three elements without any order.

Answer (score 1):

a) There are $\binom{8}{6}$ possibilities.

b) He can only choose 3 question among the 5 last, i.e. $\binom{5}{3}$.

c) He can choose 3 questions among the 4 first and 2 questions among the last 4 or 4 question among the four first and 2 among the 4 last, i.e. $$\binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{2}.$$

Why are you talking about permutation ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not giving actual answers but trying to resolve your confusions.

I wouldn't say the questions are 'specific'.  Each one is either answered or not answered, but the statistically important bit is that they are **added together in aggregation for consideration** (answer $6$ questions in total).  Thus, for example, answering question number $123678$ is same as $123876$; the **order** (i.e. permutations) doesn't matter (e.g. answering which ones first).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a finite set $A$, so $\exists$ natural $n$: $|A|=n$, there  are no problems thinking $A$ as $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Let's define permutations and combinations:

**Permutations** of ${A}:=\big\{ f: \{1,2,...,n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,...,n\}$ bijective$\big\}$
**Combinations** of $k$ elements extract form $A:=\big\{ S \subseteq A: |S|=k\big\}$

**Very importatnt facts**:

- You can think a permutation of $A$ as a $n$-tuple with all different entries because of a bijection (e.g: let $A=\{1,2,3\}$. $(2,1,3)$ represent the permutation $f: f(1)=2$ etc). In $n$-tuples order matter.
- Combinations are sets (subset of $A$)! When you consider a set order doesn't matter.